# Expanding div on hover in a flex row wrap container causes shifting of children elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, row

I was coding some css/html elements and met this problem. Been scouring over the web for potential solutions but none seem to address my problem.

I have a dynamic number of child elements needed to be fit into a parent element (flex container) for display. The child elements are sort of like badges where you can display information. On hover, the child element should expand with a width transition and reveal a utility icon for me to click on. All's fine here so far. The problem is when hovering, because the child will expand, if it is the 'last' child of the row in the flex, it will move to the next row and expand fully and i cannot reach the icon anymore.

Are there any solutions to this? I tried negative margin on the child to trick it to staying on the same row it is on but the child itself has its whole body cut off by the parent container as it overflows (it doesnt look very nice either).

I also tried forcing only n number of child elements per row (such as 2 children per row) but that only decreases the chances of the problem occuring, does not effectively remove it.

What I hope to look for is to keep the width transition and allow dynamic amount of children elements to populate into the parent container element and populate as many child element per row (hence the flex row wrap), whilst all the children being flushed to the left.

The '&' in the demo (below) is the icon; notice how some child elements at the end of some rows cannot be reached on hover as they break into the next row.

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-badge {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.5vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddenIconTray {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.flex-badge:hover > .hiddenIconTray {
  width: 20px;
}

.flex-badge:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor sit

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please check both examples I provided in my solution when you have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

One clever workaround you can use in situations like this is to allocate the amount of spacing you will want to use even before you need it.

There are a few steps needed here…

- We know these `flex-badge` elements might wrap onto the next line once expanded, so we can anticipate that might adding a `margin-right` value of the exact size we know the width will increase by, which you set to `20px`. Because you already had some margins in place to space these flex elements apart, I moved your original margins to the `gap` property set on the parent, which is the intended use of that property. This is officially supported in all modern browsers ([caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap)).
- In order to make this `margin` change, we must also account for the fact that adding `margin-right: 20px` to all `flex-badge` elements will add an unwanted gap between each element. We can counteract this side-effect by also adding `margin-left: -20px` to all `flex-badge` elements preemptively.
- On hover, we'll want to transition this `margin-right` value on the hovered element to `0` to fluidly decrease that pre-allocated space as the space filled by the element's `hiddenIconTray` child increases to fill the void.
- As this will also cause any elements that are the first in their row to also bleed from the left side of the parent container, we pair this with a `padding-left: 20px` that we apply to the parent element.

That's it! A fully functioning container where elements wrap to the next line early, if they would have done so on hover. Voila ✨

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5vw 0.5vh;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.flex-badge {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s, margin-right 0.5s;
}

.flex-badge {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.flex-badge {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.hiddenIconTray {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.flex-badge:hover {
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flex-badge:hover > .hiddenIconTray {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor sit

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

There's one last piece of this that still begs more attention. The items now overlap each other rather than pushing and pull each other as they grow and shrink. This is unfortunately unavoidable using only CSS as it is a result of the margin tweaking we performed.

However, if you are open to using a little JavaScript, we can get this working perfectly with the help of a simple loop to add a class to the first element in each flex row so we can style identify those and apply custom styles based on flex-rows rather than flex items. This is a feature not yet supported in CSS, but hopefully down the row, we'll be given with pseudo-classes for flex and grid rows and columns. This paired with the upcoming `:has()` pseudo selector would make this possible using only CSS.

We can also make use of the built-in ResizeObserver API, which is supported across all modern browsers ([caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/resizeobserver)).

Here it is in action:

```js
const flexBadgesContainer = document.querySelector('.flex-container');
const flexBadges = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-badge');
const markFirstOfFlexRows = () => {
  let currentOffsetTop = null;
  for (const badge of flexBadges) {
    if (badge.offsetTop !== currentOffsetTop) {
      currentOffsetTop = badge.offsetTop;
      badge.classList.add('flex-row-first');
    }
  }
}
markFirstOfFlexRows();
new ResizeObserver(() => {
  for (const badge of flexBadges) badge.classList.remove('flex-row-first');
  markFirstOfFlexRows();
}).observe(flexBadgesContainer);
```

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5vw 0.5vh;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.flex-badge {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s, margin-right 0.5s;
}

.flex-badge {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.flex-badge {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.hiddenIconTray {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.flex-badge:hover {
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flex-badge:hover ~ .flex-badge:not(.flex-row-first) {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.flex-badge:hover ~ .flex-badge.flex-row-first + .flex-badge {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.flex-badge:hover > .hiddenIconTray {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor sit

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem

    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">ipsum dolor
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-badge">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div class="hiddenIconTray">
      &nbsp;
      <i class="icon">&</i>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I added `resize: both` to the `.flex-container` element in the example above so you can experiment with this and see that it works even as the parent element `.flex-container` changes in size.

Comment: Great, detailed answer - thanks Brandon! As I suspected the problem is more involved than it looked initially. I came to the same conclusion as you: that the crux is to identify which elements are the last (or first) on their rows, and for that you need something more than CSS.


I ended up taking a similar approach, though in my case using the Vue framework rather than native browser JS.

+1 for working examples and checking browser support. Have some bounty!

Comment: @user2993689 thanks! Yes, I also took a look at this and at first glance thought this would be very simple using only CSS. Just goes to show me a bit more about flex/grid limitations. I hope to see the limits extended in the coming years.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified width: 40vw of `<div class="flex-container">`, child elements of this div will try to fit within the specified area which is 40vw.

I suggest you set `min-width: 40vw` and `max-width: 50vw` so that when you hover on child elements the parent div will stretch up to 50vw.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That is normal flex behavior, if element is too big, it flows down. Only way for you to do it, is to save the space for icon to appear.

https://jsfiddle.net/rm9j8cb3/2/

Check how its done. You have padding-right on badge element, that is covered via `::before` element to 'hide it' so it looks like white space. Then when hovering badge, icon appears from left, over that `::before` element and shows itself. If item was supposed to be too big, it would already fall down.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small improvement over Brandon's answer. You can instead use margin-right on the parent component, and then transition to `margin-right: 0;` when one of the children are hovered over.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-right: 6rem;
}

ul:has(> li:hover) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Therefore, the child will have enough space to expand to (you need to tweak the `margin-right` according to the size taken when expanding).
This feature is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has) on all latest browser releases, but old versions probably won't. It depends on how much you care about supporting these.